# Issue Creating a Unique Default Value for Id using Grid in Telerik ASP.NET Core for Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, grid, telerik

In the following code from the Telerik website, it shows how to CRUD a product. I implemented this code and it doesn't work because the Grid does not create a value for the ProductID before sending it to the server. Without setting the ProductID value the Grid does not know that the model it is receiving back is the one that it sent. Therefore, it doesn't mark the model as "created". When I create another record, it sends the first record along with it.

I think I need to set a default value for the ProductID but can't figure out how. How do I generate a unique ProductID for each product created?

[Link to code](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/editing-inline)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Discontinued).Width(100);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))
    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Grid"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
))
```

They link to this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/editing/ajax-editing) about how to create a datasource. What they forget to mention is that the northwind database automatically generates the ProductID. In my code, I want to generate it in the browser but can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Kendo().Grid. It doesn't support using Guids as the Id. Switching the Id type to strings solves the problem.

Comment: Kendo's Grid widget (and all the others) are very well capable to use `Guid`s as ids. I am using it almost all the time. And I suggest not to create the `ProductID` in the client. First of all: The server should never trust the client. Secondly is your server relying on the client. If you decide to change the client, you would have to reimplement this business logic.

Comment: I am generating the Ids on the server now but I am not able to use Guids yet. I'll ask that to their support and see how. Thanks for the tip.